# Calling a service in a service and returning async result?

Tags: angular, wakanda

Using Angular 5. A component calls a service. This service must call another service before making a server call. I am not able to get the result asynchronously in the component. I use ellipses for brevity below.

Component:

```
...
import { SystemOnlineService } from '../services/system-online.service';
...
constructor(private sys: SystemOnlineService) {
    sys.getStatus()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

SystemOnlineService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Wakanda } from './wakanda.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
...
getStatus() {

    this.wakanda.getCatalog()
    .then((ds) => {
        this.ds = ds;
        this.ds.Rpc_reportObjectHelper.isMySystemUp()
        .then(statusArr => {
            return statusArr;
        });
    });
}
```

The component throws this error about the `sys.getStatus()` call:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

If I `console.log(sys.getStatus());`, it logs `undefined`.

I think I am just missing something about how to properly make async calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the 'getStatus()' should return a promise. Now, it is returning nothing.
You can rewrite this way:

```
getStatus() {

  return new Promise( resolve => {
    this.wakanda.getCatalog()
    .then((ds) => {
        this.ds = ds;
        return this.ds.Rpc_reportObjectHelper.isMySystemUp()
        .then(statusArr => {
            resolve(statusArr);
        });
    });
  })
}
```

Or, event better, if this block of code does not have any toher logic, you can remove unecessary code (using arrow functions):

```
getStatus() {
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    this.wakanda.getCatalog()
    .then( ds => ds.Rpc_reportObjectHelper.isMySystemUp().then( data => resolve(data)) )
  })
}
```

Comment: also you should call the method on ngOnInit  method because is going to be called only once if you put the code in the constructor

Comment: Thank you, this code worked correctly for me. I'll remember to return a promise for functions that are run asynchronously.

Comment: Also Ricardo wouldn't the code be called only once even if i would put it in ngOnInit()?